# How to use json with Handlebars.java

Tags: java, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars.java to apply json data.  I took the below example from https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java where it was for handlebars.js and I expect the same will work in handlebars.java

```
public class TestHandlebars {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"name\": \"world\"}";
        Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
        handlebars.registerHelper("json", Jackson2Helper.INSTANCE);

        Context context = Context
            .newBuilder(json)
            .resolver(JsonNodeValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    JavaBeanValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    FieldValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    MapValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    MethodValueResolver.INSTANCE
            )
            .build();
        Template template = handlebars.compileInline("Hello {{name}}!");
        System.out.println(template.apply(context));
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output as

Hello world!

whereas I am getting just

Hello  !

What am I missing?  I have seen the examples like with Jackson views with java model "Blog" at https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java, but can't this be achieved without using java model objects for that json?

Answer (score 8):

Just found out that passing the json as JsonNode object works.

```
public class TestHandlebars {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"name\": \"world\"}";
        JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
        Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
        handlebars.registerHelper("json", Jackson2Helper.INSTANCE);

        Context context = Context
            .newBuilder(jsonNode)
            .resolver(JsonNodeValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    JavaBeanValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    FieldValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    MapValueResolver.INSTANCE,
                    MethodValueResolver.INSTANCE
            )
            .build();
        Template template = handlebars.compileInline("Hello {{name}}!");
        System.out.println(template.apply(context));
    }
}
```

Comment: ultimately, this is my problem with handlebars.java...for all its bells and whistles they _failed_ to provide a simple example that takes JSON string or Java Map object as input to the template...but if i didn't find handlebars.java so frustrating i wouldn't have found out that there is a separate project that's also a derivative of mustache.js aptly named [mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)

Answer (score 4):

Using Gson you can do this very easily without having to register a bunch of converters.

```
String data = "{\"subject\": \"World\"}";
String decoration = "Hello {{subject}}!";

Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(data, type);   

Template template = handlebars.compileInline(decoration);
Context context = Context.newBuilder(map).build();

String output = template.apply(context);
```

Comment: Passing data as Map works fine. But is there any possibility to pass data as JsonObject and make it work? It's not working for me. Any help would be appreciated